# Sqlite: get max value set to zero when row doesn't exist or is null

Tags: sqlite, null, max

I have this table `equip_info`:

```
   equip_id | fam_id | asset_no
  ----------|--------|-----------
    1       | 1      |  1
    2       | 1      |  2
```

I would like to insert a new `equip_id` from a different `fam_id` and to get the `asset_no` incremented.

If I do so:

```
INSERT INTO equip_info (fam_id, asset_no)
VALUES (1, (SELECT MAX(asset_no) + 1 FROM equip_info WHERE fam_id = 1))
```

I get below result:

```
   equip_id | fam_id | asset_no
  ----------|--------|-----------
    1       | 1      |  1
    2       | 1      |  2
    3       | 1      |  3
```

But, if I do so:

```
INSERT INTO equip_info (fam_id, asset_no)
VALUES (2, (SELECT MAX(asset_no) + 1 FROM equip_info WHERE fam_id = 2))
```

it said: `NOT NULL constraint failed: equip_info.asset_no`

If the fam_id = 2 doesn't exist how can I get increment to 1 instead?

I would like to get this result:

```
   equip_id | fam_id | asset_no
  ----------|--------|-----------
    1       | 1      |  1
    2       | 1      |  2
    3       | 1      |  3
    4       | 2      |  1
```

Remark: `equip_id` is primary key, autoincremented

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MAX(asset_no)` is NULL when there is no matching row.

To replace NULL with some other value, use [IFNULL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull), i.e., replace `MAX(asset_no)` with `IFNULL(MAX(asset_no), 0)`.